# Захват текста с сайта с помощью python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, парсер, bs4

Здравствуйте.

Пишу программу для семантического анализа на основе python. Хочу брать статьи с сайта fontanka.ru и анализировать их. Написал вот такой код:

```
# coding: utf-8
import requests
import bs4

url = requests.get('http://www.fontanka.ru/2018/04/12/086/') #подставляем url

b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")

url1 = b.select('article')
url_print = url1[0].getText()

print(url_print)
```

Он просто выхватывает текст из скопированного в код url, с помощью beautiful soup.
Далее пробую сделать окно для ввода URL, чтобы можно было парсить текст, с помощью модуля Tkinter, и никак не получается заставить программу копировать URL из поля для ввода текста, и подставлять её в модуль который написал выше. Сталкивались ли вы с таким и как это можно побороть?

Comment: А что нужно было вытащить из сайта?

Comment: Мне нужен текст статей для дальнейшего семантического анализа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_text(url):
    rs = requests.get(url)
    root = BeautifulSoup(rs.content, 'html.parser')
    article = root.select_one('article')

    return article.text


url = 'http://www.fontanka.ru/2018/04/12/086/'
text = get_text(url)
# print(text)
print(text[:100])  # Первые 100 символов из строки
```

Результат:

> '\nГора пришла к Улюкаеву\n\nИгорь Сечин впервые явился в суд по делу
> бывшего министра финансов Алексея '

Comment: Так а можно как-то для поля requests сделать модуль чтобы пользователь сам мог добавлять ссылку на сайт, а не программировать её заранее?

Comment: Не модуль, а функцию. Сейчас подправлю ответ

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)